# Need help to get started with JSNetworkX

Tags: javascript, jsnetworkx

I am just following the examples on [felix-kling](http://felix-kling.de/JSNetworkX/getting_started.html). But it just complains `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComputedStyle' of null`.I am using chrome. The same error happens when I copied the example from [anotherOne](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/LMCxT/1/) .Any ideas guys?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSNetworkX images as nodes demo</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsnetworkx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var G = jsnx.Graph();
    G.add_nodes_from([
            [1,{color:'red'}],
            [2,{color:'green'}],
            [3,{color:'white'}]
    ]);
    G.add_edges_from([[1,2],[1,3]]);

    jsnx.draw(G,{
        element: '#demo-canvas',
        node_style: {
            fill: function(d) {return d.data.color || '#AAA';}
        }
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an element with an id of `demo-canvas` so there is not element for it to draw on... your element is called `canvas` so...:

```
   jsnx.draw(G,{
        element: '#canvas',
        node_style: {
            fill: function(d) {return d.data.color || '#AAA';}
        }
    });
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/LMCxT/1/

Comment: Your link is broken. `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/jsnetworkx.js”`